# Only allow administrator to buy products in Magento frontend

Tags: magento

I need to somehow setup a Magento store to disable purchasing of a few products, and instead show a message that they can only be bought in the physical store. The twist is that the store owner/administrator has to be able to "buy" these products *on the frontend* on behalf of the customer -- all payment options are not available in the backend.

So, is there a way to only allow certain customers/users to purchase certain products, and show all other customers and anonymous visitors a "not for sale" notice? (Not "out of stock".)

I have thought of creating a special store view or custom design, or even using some Javascript trickery to prevent unauthorized visitors to purchase these products. Any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Creating a custom product attribute that identify these products

2 - Put owner/administrator in a special customer group

3 - Anywhere you have a 'add to cart' button, you check the above logic and only should 'add to cart' for those product if customer is in that owner/administrator customer group

Answer (score 0):

You could try overwriting the addAction method within the CartController (app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php), and create a conditional statement that checks the user level.

Answer (score 0):

Look forward creating Custom Shopping Cart Pricerule.
By default they do not satisfy your needs.
But this is the best place for your logic!